# Can I have two screens without two monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtualization

Long story short, I'm looking to have one monitor but two "screens" set up on my host computer (Windows 7 Ultimate). One screen will be displayed on my single monitor, while the other screen will show VirtualBox running in fullscreen mode, with a copy of Windows 8 Pro installed as my client OS. (I want to remote into this second monitor using an Android tablet and SplashTop.)

How would I go about having two different screens while only keeping one monitor hooked up?

Comment: You can RDP from a 2-monitor system to a 1-monitor system and use two monitors.  What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @SLaks - If he's talking about using the built-in Windows RDP, and running Vista or 7, that trick only works if the remote system is running Ultimate.  (This is one of very few notable differences between Ultimate and Professional).  Having said that, David, can you clarify what the host OS and/or RDP application you have in mind are?

Comment: @Shinrai: Are you sure? Are you talking about `/span` or about the `Use all monitors` checkbox? And, are you talking about the host, client, or both?

Comment: @Shinrai: The host computer (Windows 7 Ultimate) will have one physical monitor and hopefully two screens; one of which will only be visible to my tablet. The emulated client (Windows 8 Pro) will be running inside the second screen, full-size. I'll be using VirtualBox.

Comment: @SLaks - I'm talking about "Use all monitors", not that ugly-ass span mode. :)  And I believe the HOST has to have it.  (Don't quote me on that, I haven't tried in a while.  I know it's only one side though.)

Comment: @DavidIsNotHere - If the host is Win 7 Ultimate, then just use RDP with all monitors enabled.  It doesn't matter how many monitors are attached or configured on the host system at that point. (I'm guessing you haven't tried yet - the VM is irrelevant to that part, just give it a shot.)

Comment: I was really wondering if it was possible to set up two screens (on my host) when I only have one monitor running (on my host).

Comment: So the RDP stuff is irrelevant to what you're asking?  Okay, that was confusing. :)  I don't know of any way to do what you want without having multiple physical outputs on the system (even if you don't have real monitors on them, you can hook up a dummy plug or something).  That would make it awkward to work with when you're actually at the host system though...

Comment: It's a little of both, actually: I asked a question you didn't answer explicitly, but you DID point me in the right direction of exactly what I wanted to do. So, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Windows 8 on any virtualization software that supports it. The number of monitors physically attached to your PC is completely irrelevant. Your Windows 8 VM will run in the background on your host PC, then you can connect to it as you wish.

If you want to view the Windows 8 VM from the Windows 7 host, you would just switch to it just like any other application. This is also completely irrelevant of the ability for you to remotely access that VM from another computer. You would treat that VM just as any other PC.

Comment: reallly now. So as long as I had a... RDP program in Android, I would be set then? And a proper server inside of the client I'm virtualizing?

Comment: Yup. LogMeIn is a great choice, though I think you have to pay for the app on Android.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [virtual desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_virtualization) manager like:

- [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/)
- [Dexpot](http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?id=home)

Comment: Great answer, wrong direction from what I was asking (sorry for being so difficult to comprehend).

Answer (score 0):

If your monitor has multiple inputs (DVI, VGA, etc) you could hook up the two outputs from your graphics card to the single monitor.

You could switch between them using the input switch on your monitor.